# Shiny tabs are obscured by a wide sidebar

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app with a wide sidebar. When I add tabs to the main panel, the leftmost tabs are hidden behind the wide sidebar. How do I tell shiny that the main panel (and hence the tabs) start further right?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
    
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    tags$style(HTML(".main-sidebar{width: 350px;}")),
    subtitle = h5(HTML("&nbsp;&nbsp;Text12345&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Text12345"), style="color:orange"),
    splitLayout(cellWidths = c(160, 160),
                textInput(inputId = "Init1", label = NULL, value = "1"),
                textInput(inputId = "Init2", label = NULL, value = "2")
                                    ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    df <- reactive({data.frame(Nums = as.numeric(c(input$Init1, input$Init2)), y = 0)}) 
                             
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
        dat <- df()
            
        ggplot(dat) +
            geom_point(aes(x = Nums, y = y))
        }) 
  } 
  
ui <- dashboardPage(header = dashboardHeader(), 
    sidebar = sidebar,
    body = dashboardBody(mainPanel(width = 12, 
        tabsetPanel(type = "pills",
            tabPanel("Tab1", 
                fluidRow(column(6, offset = 1, box(title = "Plot", 
                                plotOutput("plot2"), width = "100%")))),
            tabPanel("Tab2", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
            tabPanel("Tab3", verbatimTextOutput("table"))))))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a margin left to the CSS element containing the body, i.e `content-wrapper`.
I added as much px as the width of the sidebar : 350px.
By the way, with the sidebar width larger, it doesn't fully collapse.It can be fixed with CSS also.

```
tags$style(HTML(".main-sidebar{width: 350px;}
                  .sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar {display:none;}
                  .content-wrapper{margin-left:350px;}"))
```